# Scala Tail Recursion Optimization on Short-Circuited Boolean Operations

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, short-circuiting

I wrote a function like this in Scala:

```
def isSorted[T](list : List[T])(compare : (T, T) => Boolean) : Boolean = {
    list match {
        case Nil => true
        case x :: Nil => true
        case x :: rest => !compare(rest.head, x) && isSorted(rest)(compare)
    }
}
```

I am curious whether the compiler will optimize away the recursive call. The recursive call can *only* happen if the leading comparison succeeds. If not, is there a way to bomb out early and still achieve tail recursion optimization?

Comment: that's what [`@annotation.tailrec`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114142/what-is-the-scala-annotation-to-ensure-a-tail-recursive-function-is-optimized) is for

Comment: Cool. It appears to be optimized. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, `@tailrec` does not magically make the method tail-recursive, it makes it an error for it not to be tail-recursive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as @omnomnom says, you can check whether something is being TCO-ed by adding the `@tailrec` annotation to the method. The compiler will throw an error if it's unable to optmise it.

We can verify this with a simple example:

```
@tailrec
def fact(n : Int) : Int = fact(n - 1) * 2
```

The compiler bombs out with the following error:

> test.scala:6: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method fact: it contains a recursive call not in tail position

Trying this on your program, however, the answer is... yes! So apparently the compiler is happy to optimise your tail-call away :-)

Comment: Interesting definition of `fact` you have there :)