# Scala compiler doesn't recognize tail recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion, scala-3, pythagorean

I am trying to create pythagorean triple series using tail recursion, but the compiler doesn't seem to recognize it as such even though I am not making any calculations in the return statement.

Error code is this: `Cannot rewrite recursive call: it is not in tail position`

Here is the code for tail recursion:

```
  def tailPythagorean(positiveNumber: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
  return tailRunner(positiveNumber, positiveNumber, List())
    .take(positiveNumber);
  }

  @tailrec def tailRunner(biggerNumber: Int, smallerNumber: Int, list: List[(Int, Int, Int)]): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    if (biggerNumber == 0 || smallerNumber == 0) {
      return list;
    }

    val smallNumber = if (smallerNumber == 1) biggerNumber - 1 else smallerNumber - 1;
    
    return tailRunner(biggerNumber, smallNumber, List((((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) - (smallerNumber * smallerNumber)), (2 * (biggerNumber + 1) * smallerNumber), ((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) + (smallerNumber * smallerNumber)))) ::: list);
  }
```

And here is the code for the recursive solution that is not optimized for tail recursion (for reference):

```
def recursivePythagorean(positiveNumber: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
  return recursiveRunner(positiveNumber, positiveNumber)
    .take(positiveNumber);
  }

  def recursiveRunner(biggerNumber: Int, smallerNumber: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    if (biggerNumber == 0 || smallerNumber == 0) {
      return List();
    }
    if (smallerNumber == 1) {
      return recursiveRunner(biggerNumber - 1, biggerNumber - 1) ::: List((((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) - (smallerNumber * smallerNumber)), (2 * (biggerNumber + 1) * smallerNumber), ((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) + (smallerNumber * smallerNumber))));
    }
    else {
      return recursiveRunner(biggerNumber, smallerNumber - 1) ::: List((((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) - (smallerNumber * smallerNumber)), (2 * (biggerNumber + 1) * smallerNumber), ((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) + (smallerNumber * smallerNumber))));
    }
  }
```

EDIT: It was indeed the presence of return keyword that was making the compiler complain, per @AminMal and @Jörg W Mittag's comments. Removing them fixed it for me:

```
  def tailPythagorean(positiveNumber: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    tailRunner(positiveNumber, positiveNumber, List())
      .take(positiveNumber);
  }

  @tailrec def tailRunner(biggerNumber: Int, smallerNumber: Int, list: List[(Int, Int, Int)]): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    if (biggerNumber == 0 || smallerNumber == 0) {
      return list;
    }
    if (smallerNumber == 1) {
      tailRunner(biggerNumber - 1, biggerNumber - 1, List((((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) - (smallerNumber * smallerNumber)), (2 * (biggerNumber + 1) * smallerNumber), ((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) + (smallerNumber * smallerNumber)))) ::: list);
    }
    else {
      tailRunner(biggerNumber, smallerNumber - 1, List((((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) - (smallerNumber * smallerNumber)), (2 * (biggerNumber + 1) * smallerNumber), ((biggerNumber + 1) * (biggerNumber + 1) + (smallerNumber * smallerNumber)))) ::: list);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try putting the last 2 lines of your tailrec function in else block, and also, It's better not to use the return keyword, you're not doing it imperatively :)

Comment: Your tailrec code compiles for me without error (Scala 2.13.3). BTW, experienced Scala programmers never, _never_, use `return`. [Here's why.](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html)

Comment: Also, `tailRunner()` is not an accurate implementation of the `recursiveRunner()` algorithm: `biggerNumber` is never actually decremented.

Comment: Good catch on the logical error @jwvh! I think it compiled for you without error because @tailrec flag is brought up at Scala 2.8, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3114248/14145407)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tail recursive methods and local functions are not allowed to use `return` for the tail recursive call. Simply remove the `return` keyword from the last line.